# Stream.pause is not a function when uploading file to stream to azure

Tags: node.js, express, azure-blob-storage, multer

I declare my `multer` configuration as follows:

```
const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1000 * 1000 * 10 // 10 Megabytes
  },
  storage: storage
});
```

And then in my express route:

```
...//On api.post() {}
console.log(file);
...
```

This outputs the file, with a buffer, which is great! However when I call:

`createBlockBlobFromStream(containerName, fileName, file, size)`

I get the error `stream.pause is not a function` which is called by the `azure-storage` at the start of the upload because the sdk wants to wait to get a `200` from the azure cloud blob service before it continues, which makes sense.

However it doesn't think that my file that I pass through has the property `pause()`.

Anyone come across this before? I read somewhere that the stream created by `multer` is not the correct formant and I need to wrap it in `streamifier` or some other package.

Comment: That's because a `buffer` is not a `stream`. Better try with https://github.com/MantaCodeDevs/multer-azure-storage

Comment: Do you want to put this in as the answer so I can mark it as answered? It was the issue and infact `multer` alpha currently supports stream so I am just using that package at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: thanks! I just answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that a **buffer** do not correspond with a **stream**. Better take a look to [multer-azure-storage](https://github.com/MantaCodeDevs/multer-azure-storage) is easier.
e.g.

```
var multer = require('multer')
var MulterAzureStorage = require('multer-azure-storage')
var upload = multer({
  storage: new MulterAzureStorage({
    azureStorageConnectionString: 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/',
    azureStorageAccessKey: 'myaccesskey',
    azureStorageAccount: 'mystorageaccount',
    containerName: 'photos',
    containerSecurity: 'blob'
  })
})
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I didnt use this but it is more than acceptable as a working solution and the `multer-azure-storage` is a good package for this use case. Thanks.